# Windows: how to send a signal (SIGNINT or SIGBREAK) to a process from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, signals, sigint

What is the best way to send a signal like `SIGINT` or `SIGBREAK` to a process from Windows command line? In my case, I want to send the *CTRL-Break* event from with a batch file to a running *java* process.

I'm looking for **no programmatical solutions**, but an already existing command line tool. It should be publicly available from a trustworthy source.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

The [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) suggests it might do what you describe, although it may be that you don't have an active window for your process.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach. Actually, I have a console, however this one won't be in foreground. AFAIK, AutoHotkey will send events always to the active windows.